# Corneal transplant and HLA matching

Tags: human-biology, human-eye, transplantation, mhc

Is HLA matching/ blood grouping required for corneal transplants ? I think,it shouldn't be, because cornea is avascular.

I tried searching on the net but most of the references are old and controversial. So please provide a reliable and latest reference for your answer.

Comment: Just because it's avascular doesn't mean immune cells can't/don't infiltrate. There are plenty of inflammatory eye processes where the cornea and lens can be targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cornea is considered as an "immune-privileged" site and tissue, neither HLA nor blood grouping is required for allogeneic corneal transplant.

In terms of reference:
This could be one: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2802514/